# Why Kattappa didn't kill Bhallaladeva

Tags: plot-explanation, character, baahubali-2-the-conclusion

In *Baahubali 2 : The Conclusion*, Amarendra Bahubali was killed by Kattappa as ordered by Rajamata because she thought he trying to kill the King.

Then after realising the truth, Rajamata Shivagami Devi announced Mahendra Bahubali(the baby) as the king.

Then Bijjaladeva asked his men to kill Rajamata and Mahendra Bahubali(The King).

The same crime that raised against Bahubali (**Tried to kill the king**).

Then why Kattappa never tried to kill Bhallaladeva or Bijjaladeva in the 25 years?

Comment: I believe Kattappa answered this question himself near the end of the movie, when he said he'd been serving the wrong person for 25 years because he believed Mahendra was dead. Not posting as an answer since I don't have the movie on me and I can't rule out the possibility of a mistranslation in the subtitles I was using.

Comment: That's right. even he think Mahendra is dead, His mother Devasena (Anushka) is there and she will be the Rajamata (because Shivagami Devi announced Mahendra as the king. Since Sivagami is dead, Devasena will be next). Then why kattappa didn't tried to save her.

Comment: When kattappa asked for her permission, she told that her son will come. But it is his duty to protect her when Bhallaladeva tortures her. He didn't do that.

Answer (score 4):

You might be mixing up some plot elements here.

Obviously, Kattappa is bound to serve the throne. Killing or executing someone is the power that Rajmatha Shivagami had. Therefore, he killed Amrendra.

When Shivagami declared Mahendra as new king, Kattappa was bound to serve Mahendra, but Bhallaldeva attacked his mother with an arrow and she fell into water.

**At that time, everybody had assumed that Shivagami and Mahendra are dead. Therefore, Kattappa has to serve Bhallaldeva and due to vow, he couldn't kill Bhallal for 25 years.**

**But when he found that Mahendra is alive, he started to obey him.**

> **Kattappa to Mahendra**: We all thought you were dead, but your grandma gave you life by sacrificing her breath.

Comment: +1 for the answer but _Killing or executing someone is the power that Rajmatha Shivagami had. Therefore, he killed Amrendra_ When Shivagami ordered to kill Bahubali, Bhallala was the king

Comment: Yes he was, but that power only Shivagami had. Try to remember the part when Bijjaldeva asked Bhalla to give an order to kill Baahubali. This was after the intermission.

Comment: So, when Bhallala and Bijjala tried to kill Shivagami, Kattappa tried to Save her. When he fall down and the opponents put their swords on his neck, he didn't moved. *If he is a real slave, then he should sacrifice his life to save her. Why he didn't tried to wake up and kill Bhallala*